# What's wrong with this simple view function?

Tags: django, django-views

The models.py file conatains:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

The forms.py file contains:

```
class StoryForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
```

The views.py file contains:

```
def story(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        story_form = StoryForm(request.POST)
        if story_form.is_valid():
            story_form.cleaned_data['author'] = request.user.id
```

The problem here has to be one of these 4 options:

1. Story.author must be a "User" instance because objects in Form.cleaned_data dict are converted to python objects by to_python() method
2. Form.cleaned_data is not yet defined
3. Form.cleaned_data must only be filled in the Form.clean() or `Form.clean_<field_name>()` methods
4. Nothing is wrong

My best guess was 3, because I thought that 2 is invalid because cleaned_data is a predefined function, and I couldn't really make sense of 1. Which of the 4 is the real issue?

Comment: Why would you alter `cleaned_data` after you call `.is_valid()`?

Comment: @Alex The code is not actually mine, I'm just trying to figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Number 3, in this case :)

Comment: @Alex Why is that?

Comment: Because if you want to pass in the author for that model form you either override form's `__init__` and pass it alongside `request.POST` or pass it directly in `request.POST` through a hidden form field which stores `request.user.id`.

There are too many unknowns regarding the desired flow to point to a specific solution.

Comment: @Alex Made a minor change to #3. Does that change the answer?

Comment: Are these coming from some kind of Django quiz? Where?